# using RequireJS for loading the jQuery Mobile bower component

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, bower

I'm developing a test web app.
I'm using

- RequireJS
- Backbone
- lodash
- bower

I'd like to use jQuery Mobile too, so I've installed it by typing

```
bower install jquery-mobile --save
```

Now I have all the jqm project in my default "bower-components" folder.

After then, I've added jqm path in the requirejs config section

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '../scripts/app',
    paths: {
        jquery: '../../bower_components/jquery/jquery.min',
        jquerymobile: '../../bower_components/jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile',
        underscore: '../../bower_components/lodash/lodash',
        backbone: '../../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        text: '../../bower_components/requirejs-text/text',
    },
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
```

Here the [loaded jquery.mobile.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.js)

Now, when I launch the app, requirejs tries to load all jqm submodules (defined in the previous linked file) from my app root "app" and not from jqm module path "bower_components".

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever come up with an answer to this? I am encountering a similar issue.